# Do the mleccha civilizations become stronger than the vedic civilization in kali yuga?

Tags: dharma, kali-yuga, mleccha

Does Hindu scripture say that Hindus will become weaker compared to the mleccha races/civilizations in kali yuga?

The puranas and itihasas say that when sattva guna is prominent in the universe, the devas and rishis become strong. When rajo guna is prominent, the asuras and nagas become strong. And when tamo guna is prominent, rakshasas and pisachas become strong (and the others become weak and powerless). Does this same concept apply to different human races? Like are mlecchas more prosperous and stronger in kali yuga, whereas the vedic civilization is stronger in satya yuga?

Do scriptures say that the mleccha civilizations will outperform Hindu civilization in kali yuga, the time of mlecchas?

Comment: there has never been a time when asuras/rakshasas didn't persecute the poor, weak & brahmins.. only the quantity differs in different yugas. and there is no special rule for one yuga vs. another, it's always the same - **you** follow your dharma. whatever follow up question you have, the answer is always the same - you follow your dharma. the only valid question is - what is my dharma? you already know the answer, but are not following it. go ask your elders if you've forgotten. if they've forgotten, ask their elders, if they've forgotten, ask acharyas. There will always be an acharya for you.

Comment: @ram Me personally?

Comment: @ram Your dharma is your path to perfection. In my experience of self-observation in meditation, every man is born with his dharma. His uniqueness, what makes him/her their own. I was born with my truth, my morality, my religion. Communists tried to cut me off from my truth and accept their socialism.

Comment: @Ikshvaku, no in general

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do the mleccha civilizations become stronger than the vedic civilization in kali yuga?

**Yes, kali yuga is when the destruction of Vedic civilization and the rise of the *Mleccha* civilizations happens.**

From the *[Vishnu Purana](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp117.htm#page_466)* on the symptoms of Kali Yuga:

> The people of the various countries intermingling with them will follow their example, and the **barbarians [mlecchas] being powerful** in the patronage of the princes, **whilst purer tribes [Vedic civilization] are neglected**, the people will perish.

Translator H.H. Wilson says in the footnote to that verse:

> The commentator, having no doubt the existing state of things in view, interprets the passage somewhat differently: the original is, ###. **The comment explains 'strong', and adds, the Mlechchhas will be in the centre, and the Áryyas at the end:' meaning, if any thing, that the unbelievers are in the heart of the country, and the Hindus on the borders: ... All that the text intends, is to represent infidels and foreigners high in power, and the Brahmans depressed.**

The Vayu Purana also says that Hindus will adopt Mleccha beliefs in kali yuga, and even inter-marry with them:

> 'Intermixed with them, the nations, adopting every where barbaric institutions, exist in a state of disorder, and the subjects shall be destroyed.'

The symptoms of Kali yuga are especially found in the Western (Mleccha) civilizations:

> Wealth and piety will decrease day by day, until the world will be wholly depraved. Then property alone will confer rank; wealth will be the only source of devotion; passion will be the sole bond of union between the sexes; falsehood will be the only means of success in litigation; and women will be objects merely of sensual gratification ... mutual assent will be marriage; fine clothes will be dignity... Gold, jewels, diamonds, clothes, will all have perished, and then hair will be the only ornament with which women can decorate themselves. Wives will desert their husbands, when they lose their property; and they only who are wealthy will be considered by women as their lords... The minds of men will be wholly occupied in acquiring wealth; and wealth will be spent solely on selfish gratifications. Women will follow their inclinations, and be ever fond of pleasure. Men will fix their desires upon riches, even though dishonestly acquired... The women will be fickle, short of stature, gluttonous: they will have many children, and little means: scratching their heads with both hands, they will pay no attention to the commands of their husbands or parents: they will be selfish, abject, and slatternly: they will be scolds and liars: they will be indecent and immoral in their conduct, and will ever attach themselves to dissolute men.

In India:

> the Brahmanical thread will constitute a Brahman; external types (as the staff and red garb) will be the only distinctions of the several orders of life;... Amidst all castes he who is the strongest will reign over a principality thus vitiated by many faults... Men of all degrees will conceit themselves to be equal with Brahmans.

So, the conclusion is that kali yuga is the time when mleccha races prosper.

Answer (score 5):

> "Śukadeva Gosvāmī said: Then, O King, religion, truthfulness,
>   cleanliness, tolerance, mercy, duration of life, physical strength and
>   memory will all diminish day by day because of the powerful influence
>   of the Age of Kali. -- [ŚB 12.2.1](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/2/1/)

Age of Kali affects all human race. Yes, in age of Kali mlecchas will be predominant and sattvic people, or people who practice spiritual life, will be in minority. Gradually, those irreligious mlecchas will bring themselves to destruction. Only small number or spiritual people will survive.

> "Texts 12-16: By the time the Age of Kali ends, the bodies of all
>   creatures will be greatly reduced in size, and the religious
>   principles of followers of varṇāśrama will be ruined. The path of the
>   Vedas will be completely forgotten in human society, and so-called
>   religion will be mostly atheistic. The kings will mostly be thieves,
>   the occupations of men will be stealing, lying and needless violence,
>   and all the social classes will be reduced to the lowest level of
>   śūdras. Cows will be like goats, spiritual hermitages will be no
>   different from mundane houses, and family ties will extend no further
>   than the immediate bonds of marriage. Most plants and herbs will be
>   tiny, and all trees will appear like dwarf śamī trees. Clouds will be
>   full of lightning, homes will be devoid of piety, and all human beings
>   will have become like asses. At that time, the Supreme Personality of
>   Godhead will appear on the earth. Acting with the power of pure
>   spiritual goodness, He will rescue eternal religion." -- [ŚB
>   12.2.12-16](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/2/12-16/)

Comment: I edited your answer further and undeleted it.